# How can I mock parent class members or its methods using mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, parent-child, static-methods

Here is the scenario wherein I want to mock the object creation of A inside the parent which is happening through a static method or it can even from a static block of defined in some of its Child

```
abstract class Parent{
    A a;
    static createA(){
        // some logic behind creating Object A
        a = new A();
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        a.foo();
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent{
    static{
        createA();
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the object A inside the Parent class when doSomething() is being called from the child object.

Comment: do you really need to do this to create the "A" object? It seems a bit like architecture smell for me. Maybe it will be better to create A outside of this class and inject it through the constructor? In that case, in test you can just do: `new Child1(mock(A.class))`

Comment: I believe , my application designed to have a singleton Object (of A) for serverless application.  and the Parent can be considered as a AbstractRequestHandler and each lambda will be inheriting this parent handler

Comment: Is the `a` object package-private? if so, you can put your test in the same package as Parent class and do something like:
`Child1 ch = new Child1(); ch.a = mock(A.class);`